# Compile Error VBA Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
Option Compare Database

Sub RunTest()
    Call autoexec
End Sub


Function autoexec() 
On Error GoTo autoexec_Err
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False 
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "delete alerttest", acViewNormal, acEdit
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "alerttestquery", acViewNormal, acEdit
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "alerttestdatequery", acViewNormal, acEdit
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "namequery", acViewNormal, acEdit
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "timediffquery", acViewNormal, acEdit
    DoCmd.OpenTable "alerttest", acViewNormal, acEdit
autoexec_Exit:
    Exit Function

autoexec_Err:
  MsgBox Error$
  Resume autoexec_Exit

  Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "RunTest"

End Function
```

Getting a compile error on Application.OnTime can i ask why?

Answer (score 0):

Because `Application.OnTime` exists only in Excel VBA.

You need to use a **Form** with its `OnTimer` event, set the `TimerInterval` property to 10000 ms.

The form can be hidden, if necessary.